# Android opening Instagram intent with image causes crash

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

I am developing an app for Android which should have the functionality to take a picture, and share it to the Instagram app.
The app opens up the camera, takes a picture and then the Instagram app is opened with the "Crop photo" window active. It seems to be loading the picture, but after a couple of seconds the app crashes, i can't see that the image ever gets loaded.

I am developing the app on top of Appcelerators Titanium platform, however i do not think that my problem is related to Titanium, but rather how i pass the image.

Since the emulator doesn't have the Instagram app, i am developing on my Galaxy S4. I have tried running logcat through adb to get some sort of error message to help me, but only thing i see is that it notices that Instagram exited.

Here is my code, what could be wrong? I have checked that the image is saved into the filesystem.

```
Ti.Media.showCamera({
success: function(event) {
    var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.tempDirectory,"ggs-instagram.jpg");
    file.write(event.media);
    var instaIntent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
        action: Ti.Android.ACTION_SEND,
        packageName: "com.instagram.android",
        type: 'image/jpeg'
    });
    /*instaIntent.putExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_TEXT, "EXTRA_TEXT");
    instaIntent.putExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "EXTRA_SUBJECT");*/
    instaIntent.putExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_STREAM, file.getNativePath());
    Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(instaIntent);
},
cancel: function() {},
error: function (error) {
    if (error.code == Ti.Media.NO_CAMERA)  {
        alert("Din telefon/platta har ingen kamera!");
    } else {
        alert("Kamerafel!");
    }
},
mediaTypes:         [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO,Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO],
showControls:       false,
autohide:           false,
saveToPhotoGallery: true
});
```

Comment: I had seen a similar issue online almost six months back(dont have the link) where the solution was to add FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to the intent and that had worked for a similar problem. Try that.

Comment: @Slartibartfast unfortunately it made no difference :/

Comment: Well see if there is a known internal issue with Instagram itself from their website like here: http://help.instagram.com/379302862144995/

Comment: Also it would help if you posted some logcat - even if its garbled junk- maybe someone here would understand it :)

Comment: please add log for above crash

Answer (score 0):

pls take a look at

[Instagram from Android open on certain user and add caption to uploaded image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002468/instagram-from-android-open-on-certain-user-and-add-caption-to-uploaded-image)

[Instagram Option in Sharing Intent Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308626/instagram-option-in-sharing-intent-android/14954551#14954551)

[Android: post image and text to Instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563426/android-post-image-and-text-to-instagram)

Comment: None of those links answered my question. I have been looking at those questions before, and use it as reference when i implemented my solution, but still doesn't work