# API of Instagram and Blogger in android

Tags: android, api, instagram, blogger

In one of my application there a requirement for sharing image or text on **Instagram** and **Blogger**. I would like to know is there any API available for android to share details on Instagram and blogger. Any kind of tutorial or demo will be more helpful.

Please help me for this. I searched for [Instagram](http://blog.instagram.com/post/20418620347/getting-started-on-instagram-for-android) but its not helpful to me.

If any one have information about it please share.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so much of surfing i found the information about the [Instagram integration in Android](http://b2cloud.com.au/uncategorized/instagram-integration-in-an-android-app) with the [Sample Application](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-instagram-oauth)

I also searched for the Blogger API in android but i found that there is no such api for the mobile development. I found the API which is for the JAVA not for the Android available yet.

[Blogger API in JAVA](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/api-lib/java) also [Blogger API JAVA Client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/shared/shared-sample-cmdline/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/shared/cmdline/oauth2/OAuth2Native.java?repo=samples&name=based-on-1.9)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't post into **Instagram**: [API doc](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/)

[post image in Instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296770/post-image-in-instagram)

[Send Text Tag to Instagram using my Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258217/send-text-tag-to-instagram-using-my-android-app)

but also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308626/instagram-option-in-sharing-intent-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563426/android-post-image-and-text-to-instagram).I don't know this worked for you

and for Blogger i think so you can.please see following link:

[posting to blogger with Google-api-java-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286783/posting-to-blogger-with-google-api-java-client)

[Blogger APIs Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/api-lib/java)

Comment: I don't know about that, Sorry

Comment: The blogger api which you have specified is for java not for android. Do you have any idea about android blogger api ?